# Funciones no sirven en mi switch

Tags: base-de-datos, c, funciones, switch, menu

Programa que realiza busqueda en una base de datos

Se cuenta con la base de datos del estado de Aguascalientes con fecha 2021 del mes de abril, y se desea buscar el
sueldo del Sr. Humberto Ramos Chavez;
Por lo que tendras que realizar un programa que cargue el archivo en Memoria y realice dos busquedas por el mismo ID:
276638993,
a) Una busqueda secuencial, anotar el número de condicionantes antes de llegar al resultado, junto con el tiempo que se
tarda en dar la respuesta.
b) Una busqueda binaria, anotar el número de condicionantes antes de llegar al resultado, junto con el tiempo que se tarda
en dar la respuesta.Si realizas de manera adecuada la busqueda binaria te daras cuenta que el resultado es "el logaritmo
base 2 de n", es decir Log2 n; o lo que es lo mismo n=2^x; por lo tanto si tomamosesta base de datos con 34595,
34595=2^x; donde x=15.0782759, por lo tanto no deberasocupar más de 16 condiciones para encontrar cualquier persona
dentro de esta base de datos.
En el mismo programa deberas dejar un ciclo para realizar cualquier otra busqueda binaria por cualquier ID.La base de
datos puedes descargarla de la Liga:
https://oficinavirtual.issste.gob.mx/Transparencia/Padr%C3%B3n-de-Derechohabientes-Activos#

Ya probé la función "buscar" por aparte y **SI** funciona, pero cuando la ingreso a mi menú, no funciona. Alguien que sepa el porque y me pueda ayudar porfavor?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

FILE *fp;
int i;
char ID[50];
char ch;
char search[20];
int contador = 0;
int pos[1000];
int pointer = 0;

void buscar();  //prototipo 
void imprimir();
int main(){
int opc;

fp = fopen("AGUASCALIENTES.txt", "r+"); //modo lectura
do{
system("cls");
printf("\t****Base de Datos de Aguascalientes****\n\n");
printf("\n 1.- Buscar un ID de una persona de forma secuencial");
printf("\n 2.- Buscar un ID de una persona de forma binaria");
printf("\n 3.- Salir");
printf("\n Opcion a escoger: ");
scanf("%i", &opc);
system("cls");

switch(opc){
    
    case 1:{ buscar();
        
    
       }
        break;
        
    case 2: buscar(); //falta hacerlo todavia
        break;
    
   }

   }while(opc != 3);



 system("pause");
  return 0;
}

void buscar(){

system("cls");
printf("Digita el ID que estas buscando: ");
scanf("%s",&search);

 do 
 {
  ch = fscanf(fp, "%s", ID); 
  if(strcmp(ID, search) == 0)
    {
     pos[contador] = pointer;     
     contador++;
    }
  pointer++;
      
} while (ch != EOF); 

if(contador == 0)  
    printf("'%s' NO fue encontrado \n", search);
else
    {
    printf("'%s' Fue encontrado en la posicion -> ", search);
    for(i = 0; i<contador; i++)
        {
            printf("%d ", pos[i]);
        }
    
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `ch` debe ser in `int`, no un `char`. Además, cuando `fscanf` devuelve `EOF`, tienes que salir **ya**; de no hacerlo, el último registro dará un resultado superior en 1.

Comment: El problema es de no inicializar `contador`, `pointer` y la posición en el archivo (`fseek(fp,0L,SEEK_SET)`). A la primera, están en 0. Pero a la segunda, no están en 0.